# Exclude element with child containing text

Tags: xml, xpath

Consider this XML:

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <field>
            <name>empId</name>
            <type>int</type>
        </field>
        <op>in</op>
        <value>eID</value>
        <valueType>PERI</valueType>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <field>
            <name>desc</name>
            <type>string</type>
        </field>
        <op>in</op>
        <value>dbDesc</value>
        <valueType>PERI</valueType>
    </filter>
</filters>
```

I want to keep the whole tree excluding the `<field>` that contains name='empId'.

The result should be:

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <field>
            <name>desc</name>
            <type>string</type>
        </field>
        <op>in</op>
        <value>dbDesc</value>
        <valueType>PERI</valueType>
    </filter>
</filters>
```

XPath 1.0 please.

Obvious stuff like `/*[not(//field/name[text()='empId'])]` doesn't work.

Comment: I don't that's possible with xpath alone; see for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528421/9448090. You'll need xquery, xslt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use below Xpath:

Updated Xpath:

```
//field//*[not(contains(.,'empId'))]
```

Above xpath will select everything expect name - emp

OR

```
//filter//field[not(contains(.,'empId'))]/*
```

Above xpath will select all fields expect the field which is having emp

...................................
...................................

Old Xpath

```
//field[not(contains(.,'empId'))]
```

OR

```
/*//filter[field[not(contains(.,'empId'))]]
```

OR

```
/*//filters//filter[field[not(contains(.,'empId'))]]
```

It will select field which are not having name as empId

Comment: The first one just returns `<fields>`s without anything else. The second returns the right `<filter>` without the containing `<filters>`.  The third returns no nodes.

Comment: Great if 2nd works for you ... you can consume same .. glad it work

Comment: 2nd does not work. I want the containing tags whatever they may be.

Comment: use this - //field//*[not(contains(.,'empId'))] .... I misunderstood the requirement in first place .. updated the answer as well